# May I play only one Tenacious Z or all of them from discard pile in my turn?

Tags: smash-up

The card text of "Tenacious Z" says:

> Special: During your turn you may play this card from your discard pile as an extra minion. You may only use the ability of one Tenacious Z each turn.

I'm not sure if that means "once for each card" or "one time each turn, no matter which card it is".
So may I play 1 or 3 Tenacious Z from discard pile when I have 3 of them in the discard pile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One.

It says

> You may only use the ability of one Tenacious Z each turn.

It doesn't say

> You may only use the ability of a Tenacious Z once each turn.

Comment: Thanks. I've played the German version of the game and I think it's much less clear than the English card is.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one extra free zombie each turn.

Comment: That's not quite right. Say a TZ started in the discard pile. As worded, you could play it as a free minion, have it sent to the discard pile by whatever means, and play it again as a free minion a second time all in the same turn, since you're only using the ability of one TZ.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens, I disagree. Yeah, it's a short answer, but the problem appears to be a lack of understanding of English by the OP, so an alternate wording of the line of text is indeed an appropriate answer. In fact, it's very hard to answer the question without simply repeating the card text. (I've already pointed out the alternate wording Josh proposed is flawed in exceptional circumstances, but it's still an answer.)